# parse the curl result using class name

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing, domdocument

I am using the curl function to get the from the other side but it is showing the complete page of the site. I wanna to show the content based on class name. Please let me know how I can do it?
I am using the following code:-

```
 <?php
 $curl = curl_init('http://www.insolvency.govt.nz/cms/search?SearchableText=smith');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $res=$dom->loadHTML($result);
 $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

 foreach($divs as $div) {
 if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'searchResult') {
     echo $div->nodeValue;
 }else{
echo "error";   
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XPath can be used to get elements by class name. The example below will get elements that have the `myClass` class.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$res=$dom->loadHTML($result);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$class = 'myClass';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($divs as $div) {
    echo $div->nodeValue;

    echo $dom->saveXML($div);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is showing the text only, hyperlink is missing. can i get the result with html ?

Comment: See my edit, you can use `$dom->saveXML($div)` to get the HTML.